# Div's in two columns

Tags: css

I have multiple number of divs that varies depending on the data it is using. Currently they are in a container div, and their width is half the container with a left float so they appear like:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9
```

etc..

I am trying to get it so that it appears like:

```
1 6
2 7
3 8
4 9
5
```

I can't seem to find a simple way to do this.

Comment: This will help: http://css-tricks.com/13372-seamless-responsive-photo-grid/

Comment: Do you want a javascript (or jQuery) solution?

Comment: Many (not all) users read left-to-right, so depending on the context of your data, this could be confusing for the user.

Comment: Is the number of items returned from your datasource variable?  Or do you only return a set number (9)?

Comment: You can use css3 column-count: 2; on the container

Comment: @Makram Saleh Javascript would be fine as long as it works in IE7+ and FireFox. jQuery can not be used.

Comment: @FiveTools - The number of items returned is variable.

Comment: @IcanDivideBy0 - It needs to work in IE7+ am I right in saying this wouldn't work in IE? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@joseph; you can use css3 `column-count` property like this

```
    div#multicolumn1 {
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-gap: 50%;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-gap: 50%;
        column-count: 3;
        column-gap: 50%;

}
```

check this example http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/pMbtk/ may be that's help you