# How to stack divs from top to bottom in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a list that goes like this:

```
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item">5</div>
```

using css float left, it looks like this in html:

```
1 2
3 4
5
```

Is it possible to style my divs to look like the following:

```
1 4
2 5
3
```

Hope someone can help, thanks!

Comment: I feel like I want little more info maybe. I mean.. to get what you want.. Youd just have to assign the content in a way that it corresponds the order that you desire. Just like what you have done with the numbers. Of course unless you want to take few things into account.. but that would work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

@ funky; you can use css3 `column-count` property for this

css:

```
div#multicolumn1 {
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-gap: 50%;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-gap: 50%;
        column-count: 3;
        column-gap: 50%;

}
```

check this link for a demo [Div's in two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843706/divs-in-two-colums/6843902#6843902)

http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/pMbtk/

*note:* it doesn't work in IE.

Comment: Fantastic!! that works great, I don't have to add another column or do any hacks! Thanks!

Comment: column-count: 2; i guess.. btw hi Funky :D

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to create two div containers for this to work. One container which holds 1-3 and one for 4-5.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to support ie, there are [css columns](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html) that would do extactly that.