# How to make div stack first vertically then horizontally?

Tags: html, css, css-float

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stack divs from top to bottom in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268447/how-to-stack-divs-from-top-to-bottom-in-css)

When i have multiple adjacent divs with `float:left`, they stack like this:

```
 _______
| 1 2 3 |
| 4 5   |
|_______|
```

I want a stack like this:

```
 _______
| 1 4   |
| 2 5   |
|_3_____|
```

[jsFiddle with the horizontal stacking](http://jsfiddle.net/WDuvs/)

How can i achieve vertical stacking ?

Comment: This is a good question, but why in first place ? you want to fill the space the user have displayed then continue to scroll to see more... 
it seems you're working on some mobile website or so

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@ pinouchon; for this type of layout you can use css3 `column-count property` for this.

CSS:

```
div#multicolumn1 {
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-gap: 10px;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
        column-count: 2;
        column-gap: 10px;

}
```

Check my example here for more [How to stack divs from top to bottom in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268447/css-how-to-style-divs-top-to-bottom/7268484#7268484)

read this article for more http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html

Comment: This [doesn't work for IE, at all](http://caniuse.com/#search=column-count).

Comment: yes; css3 column-count property is not work in IE for this you can use js http://www.csscripting.com/css-multi-column/ put this in IE comment.

Comment: This is technically not a correct solution because the css will prioritize horizontal first then vertical, for proof try to have only 2 items. OP's question seems want to prioritize vertical and then horizontal.
For prioritizing vertical and then horizontal, look into, display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: wrap;