# Vertical stack order of divs rather than horizontal?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to stack divs from top to bottom in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268447/how-to-stack-divs-from-top-to-bottom-in-css)
>   [How to make div stack first vertically then horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318819/how-to-make-div-stack-first-vertically-then-horizontally)

Floating or inline elements stack like this:

```
-----------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
-----------------
```

But I would like to stack them like this:

```
-----------------
| 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 |
| 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 |
-----------------
```

Constraints: Arbitrary number of elements. All of same size. All elements must be on the same "level", meaning we cannot stack "pairs" of divs.

Is it possible?

EDIT: Forgot to mention, the container should expand horizontally so it's ok to use a "fixed" number of "rows".

Comment: Yes, but you will have to define wrapping elements as _columns_, which are behaving like the first sample. -- Is this what you are calling _pairs_ ?

Comment: The comment on "pairs" basically meant that there is no access to server-side and thus the elements must be handled as a "flat" list with unmodifiable "order".

Comment: Possible duplicates: [CSS : How to style divs top to bottom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268447/css-how-to-style-divs-top-to-bottom) and [How to make div stack first vertically then horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318819/how-to-make-div-stack-first-vertically-then-horizontally)

Comment: You are correct @pinouchon. Sorry about the double post. I will flag this post.

Answer (score 1):

I have two solutions.

First, use the CSS3 `nth-of-type`:

`div:nth-of-type(even){margin:50px 0 0 -50px;}`

This degrades gracefully into the un-indeal ordering, but the general formatting is preserved.

Also, you can achieve a similar effect by putting a class on every other item.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/adRuz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Set your column-count to 4 on the elements parent.

```
#your-parent-element-id {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 10px;
}
```

Note that this will only work in relatively modern browsers.

See also: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/KLZUa/ for demo

Comment: Too bad half the world doesn't use a modern browser. This by itself does not solve  "All elements must be on the same 'level'" either. (emphasis mine)

Comment: @tybro0103: the elements are already on the same level, i'm not touching any elements, just css.

Comment: Just because you haven't re-arranged elements, doesn't mean they're on the same level. It still won't work in a lot of browsers.

Comment: @tybro0103: hence my note stating such

Comment: hence it's not a good solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5388/discussion-between-kris-and-tybro0103)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most manageable option that works in all browsers is to wrap every couple elements in another "column" div:

```
<div class="column">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</div><div class="column">
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div><div class="column">
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div><div class="column">
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

...

```
div.column {
  width:25%
  float:left;
}
```

Most html is served from a server-side programming language, usually with some sort of templating engine. Doing this in a templating engine such as ERB for Ruby or Smarty for PHP is  very simple.

For your "stacking" height problem, just assign a height to the inner divs

```
div.column div {
  height:200px;
}
```

Comment: -1: this does not answer the question. "All elements must be on the same "level", meaning **we cannot stack "pairs" of divs**." (emphasis mine)

Comment: It does now. Yours doesn't either. (emphasis mine)

Comment: I'm not trying to have a pissing contest, just keeping the site honest. If the author can rearrange the nodes this would a good solution. he says he can't tho.

Comment: By down-voting a very viable solution, YES, you are actually. And no, the author did not say he could not re-arrange... reread it maybe?

Comment: Sorry it does not please you to get down voted. but the author has added a comment to the question that makes this very explicitly clear. maybe you should re-read the question. I would've actually upvoted this if he hadn't been so clear about that constraint.