# How to stack up a list of divs so there's no vertical gap?

Tags: html, css

If I have a list (ul/li) of divs (with variable height), is there a way to stack them so that there are no gaps between a div and the div below it?  Like the pinterest UI...

```
    <ul>
         <li>
           <div>...</div>
         </li>
         <li>
           <div>...</div>
         </li>
         ...
    </ul>    

    ul
    {
       list-style-type:none; 
       vertical-align:top;
    }

    li
    {
       list-style:none;    
       vertical-align:top;  
       display:inline-block;   
    }
```

This is similar to the question here [How to make div stack first vertically then horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318819/how-to-make-div-stack-first-vertically-then-horizontally) except that I still want to order it like this:

```
1 2 3
4 5
```

Comment: I tried vertical-align:top, but that doesn't seem to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Following CSS is enough to create that effect

```
ul, li  { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
ul li { float: left; }
ul li div { background: #f00; color: #fff; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L2tDV/1/)

Comment: I initially thought that this worked, but 9 appears below 3, but it should appear below 1.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Prabhu, Of course it will come under 3. How will put together an algorithm to define your stacking? How will 4 appear below 1 and subsequently 9 below 4? I dont suppose There isn't any equation to give this result.

Comment: Create a full structure of what you want, then I will think if it can be achieved decently.

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to achieve the structure of pinterest.  Each line should be ordered from left to right.  I realized that my comment is irrelevant, because the order of appearance will differ based on screen resolution.  But I noticed that you solution sets the div to a fixed height.  But my divs are not fixed, they will be as high as they need to be based on the content.

Comment: @Prabhu, I think you should create a screenshot of what you want and post on your question.

Comment: @Starx...will work on the screenshot.  But you could also take a look at pinterest.com.  See how the boxes are stacked.  That's exactly the effect I am after. Thanks for your help...