# How to stack divs vertically

Tags: html, css, stack, grid-layout

So I have a bunch of divs and I want to stack them vertically.

Here's my attempt:

http://jsbin.com/bacijegi/1/

However the sequence is not right, and the items go horizontally actually.

This is what I expect:

```
 ___  ___
|   ||   |
| 1 || 4 |
|___||___|
 ___  ___
|   ||   |
| 2 || 5 |
|___||___|
 ___ 
|   |
| 3 |
|___|
```

Is there any way I can achieve this with pure css ? (without changing the html structure and javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stack divs from top to bottom in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268447/how-to-stack-divs-from-top-to-bottom-in-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to stack them vertically in multiple columns, take a look at the CSS3 `column-count` property.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-count.asp

There is a previous answer on this here, with a JSFiddle for you to see it in action:

[Div's in two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843706/divs-in-two-colums/6843902#6843902)

http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/pMbtk/